# SingalR authorized user doesn't get message back ASP.Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr

I'm trying to integrate the Identity Users with SingalR. So far, authorization is successful as far as connecting to the hub.
The problem is I can get it working with groups, but despite authorization working, I can't send directly by user. I also tried email instead of the user uniqueidentifier, but the results are the same. Would love your opinion.
Thanks.

JWT:

```
 options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
 {
      OnMessageReceived = context =>
      {
          var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&(context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/feed/get")))
          {
              context.Token = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
          }
          return Task.CompletedTask;
      }
 };
```

Startup.cs

```
 app.UseEndpoints(route =>
 {
     route.MapHub<ActivityHub>("/feed/Get");                
 });
```

Hub

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]

public class ActivityHub : Hub
{     
    IAuthService AuthService;
    public ActivityHub(IAuthService authService)
    {
        AuthService = authService;
    }

    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {

        var user = await AuthService.GetUserByNameAsync(Context.User.Identity.Name);           

        await Clients.User(user.Id).SendAsync("receiveMessage", "Hello user"); //this doesn't get recived on client

        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, user.Id);
        await Clients.Group(user.Id).SendAsync("receiveMessage", "Hello group!");//this works

        await base.OnConnectedAsync();

    }

        public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend using the groups approach, to add users in the groups when the connect, and I Microsoft actually recommends this even if you create a single user group. If you don't want that, then I hope someone will help you with your problem.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I'll do just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments section, the best approach is just use the groups to archive your goal. Just add a user in a single user group on the connected method.

As you can read on this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#single-user-groups), is common to use single user groups in SignalR.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to customize the user identifier you can implement your own IUserIdProvider like shown in the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-claims-to-customize-identity-handling

Also, when using Clients.User(...) you should be using Context.UserIdentifier to get the user ID as that is what SignalR will be using to distinguish the user.

Comment: I've seen the docs, they are very brief and I haven't been able to found a lot of examples online. I guess I will just use groups instead.